# Starting Activities from classes which does not extend Activiy

Tags: android, xml

I am extending a Relative layout in which i am Inflating an xml.I added the on Click listeners in the class..On click  i want to start another activity .I ma not able to start it as i am extending Relative layout..How to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
 this.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```